# Why has the photo gallery sorting changed after firmware update?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gallery, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-mini

Now the photo sorting in each gallery begins with the first taken one. Before the firmware update, it had begun with the last taken one, so with the latest. Even the Gallery sorting is made by earlier creation. My phone is Galaxy Mini and I upgrade from 2.3.3 to 2.3.6. I could not find any settings to change the "direction"

Comment: Humble question: what is "shorting"? Do you mean "sorting", i.e. the order in which pictures are displayed?

Comment: Ah, OK -- thanks. The answer I have to leave to somebody else, as I rarely use the gallery and thus did not notice...